# Why flutter sdk folder uploading on github instead of project?

Tags: git, flutter, github

I am new github user, i want to upload my flutter project on github, i successfully installed are required components. When i uploading my flutter project the flutter sdk folder is uploading on github instead of flutter project. I uploaded screenshot of uploaded folder or link of uploaded project. Please help.. link - > https://github.com/rakesh8561/mi2

.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you have created your flutter project folder.
And where you have done `git init .`.

If it is within a copy of [`github.com/flutter/flutter`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter), then it would be added/committed to that flutter repository, which would be in turned pushed to your new GitHub repository.

The `.git` subfolder should be within your project, not in `flutter`

If you create a new [Flutter project](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#creating-a-new-project), it should be in a folder *outside* of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you man you saved my time. Actually i was creating this into another repository, i changed it to my project repository and re commited. After that it solved.

Comment: @RakeshSaini Perfect, well done. That should work indeed.